# Replacing the login screen

Tags: grub2, login, synaptic, xserver

I removed the login screen from ubuntu because it was the wrong one... but instead of reverting back to the default screen, it just goes blank after the boot! What do I do now? I'm almost certain I can fix the problem with synaptic, but I can't get to it!

Comment: Which Ubuntu version, how was the login screen "wrong", qnd what did you do to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the screen when you choose the system to boot, or the screen when you enter username and password? If you mean the second one, then you can try: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, then choose one from the list:

1. lightdm: default for Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 (and 11.04 if I remember it correctly)
2. gdm: default for Ubuntu 10.10 and older ones.
3. kdm: for KDE. 
   Of course, if some of them does not display, then you have to install it. For example: `sudo apt-get install gdm`